# Ubuntu 20.04 'Focal' cannot find all I2C devices via i2cdetect; it get a few, though

Tags: i2c, ubuntu, raspberry-pi-os

This is puzzling me:

I use Ubuntu 20.04 'Focal' on a RPI CM4. When I run `i2cdetect -y 1` to list the connected I2C devices on `/dev/i2c-1`, I get a few addresses back that correspond to the custom PCB I have connected to the RPi. However, a few devices are missing! There are a couple of I2C devices there, including an RTC, a DAC, et.c.

Strangely, on the Raspberry Pi OS (on a RPi4, *not* a CM4) everything works fine and I get *all* connected devices when I probe the bus.

I am starting to think that since Ubuntu recognises at least *some* devices, it is probably something wrong with the CM4. Maybe an address conflict? I'd love to try Ubuntu 20.04 on the RPI4, but since it is running on a CM4, it isn't possible to simply switch the cards.

**Edit**: I did try to run Ubuntu (this time 20.10) on the RPi 4 (which also has pullups) instead of Raspberry Pi OS. Same result; some I2C devices do not get recongised in the bus. So, it probably *is* something Ubuntu-related.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said so I am going to assume you have not fitted the proper pulls to 3V3 on SDA and SCL on your compute module.  The pulls are hardwired on the other Pi models.

Comment: Whilst a good catch (the PCB has no pullups indeed!) that I need to fix in the board, the issue is probaby not the pulls. Still not detecting half the devices.